# Laravel - Heroku - Docker - 404 (Not Found) js css files from public folder

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel application on Heroku but the assets that are in public folder aren't loading.

Application url: https://drinkco.herokuapp.com

I'm already trying to force https on AppServiceProvider with the code:

```
if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS')) {
  $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
}
```

Procfile configuration : `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/`

The files are beeing generated by npm run prod

[print screen from console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrtJ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Comment: that didn't solved

Comment: Why would switching from Nginx to Apache help? Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if you included the assets folder inside of your `.gitignore` file.

If you do not want to track changes to this folder, which you shouldn't, you can include it back to your `.gitignore` file after deploying to heroku